# Creating functional tests Scala Playframework 2.6 Macwire

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I wrote some traits to use it as a base for my functional tests

This file is for creating a DB in memory (H2 + Evolutions)

BlogApiDBTest.scala

```
package functional.common

import play.api.db.Databases
import play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions

trait BlogApiDBTest {

  implicit val testDatabase = Databases.inMemory(
    name = "blog_db",
    urlOptions = Map(
      "MODE" -> "MYSQL"
    ),
    config = Map(
      "logStatements" -> true
    )
  )

  org.h2.engine.Mode.getInstance("MYSQL").convertInsertNullToZero = false
  Evolutions.applyEvolutions(testDatabase)
}
```

Here I am overriding some injected components for testing purposes

BlogApiComponentsTest.scala

```
package functional.common

import common.BlogApiComponents
import org.scalatestplus.play.components.WithApplicationComponents
import play.api.{BuiltInComponents, Configuration}

trait BlogApiComponentsTest extends WithApplicationComponents with BlogApiDBTest {

  override def components: BuiltInComponents = new BlogApiComponents(context) {
    override lazy val configuration: Configuration = context.initialConfiguration
    override lazy val blogDatabase = testDatabase
  }

}
```

This is the base class for my functional tests

BlogApiOneServerPerTestWithComponents.scala

```
package functional.common

import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import org.scalatestplus.play.components.{OneServerPerTestWithComponents}

trait BlogApiOneServerPerTestWithComponents extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerTestWithComponents with BlogApiComponentsTest {

}
```

Finally the test I am trying to execute

PostControllerSpec.scala

```
package functional.controllers

import functional.common.BlogApiOneServerPerTestWithComponents
import org.scalatest.concurrent.{IntegrationPatience, ScalaFutures}
import play.api.mvc.{Results}
import play.api.test.{FakeRequest, Helpers}


import play.api.test.Helpers.{GET, route}

class PostControllerSpec extends BlogApiOneServerPerTestWithComponents
  with Results
  with ScalaFutures
  with IntegrationPatience {

  "Server query should" should {
    "provide an Application" in {
      val Some(result) = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, "/posts"))
      Helpers.contentAsString(result) must be("success!")
    }
  }

}
```

Then I get

> blog-api/test/functional/controllers/PostControllerSpec.scala:18:31: Cannot write an instance of play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsEmpty.type to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsEmpty.type]

Here is the [code](https://github.com/agusgambina/blog-api.git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following import should make it work:

```
import play.api.test.Helpers._
```

Looking at the signature of [`route`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6768cb95c2d082665b836a7b8e61888d2f760677/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L285)

```
def route[T](app: Application, req: Request[T])(implicit w: Writeable[T]): Option[Future[Result]]
```

we see it expects an `implicit w: Writeable[T]`. The above import will provide it via [Writables](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6768cb95c2d082665b836a7b8e61888d2f760677/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L155)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I think is working because the error message has changed. I've only added the import and I did not defined route. Now I am trying to overcome the H2 error because it seems that the table is not created.

Comment: Your evolutions are under `conf/evolutions/default` however in tests you have named your database `blog_db`, so `Evolutions.applyEvolutions(testDatabase)` is going to look for it under `conf/evolutions/blog_db`. Please see [Applying-evolutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTestingWithDatabases#Applying-evolutions)